# Android record sound in real time and identify frequency

Tags: java, android, fft, android-audiorecord, frequency-analysis

im trying to detect frequency during recording in andrid

i follow those post and non of them give working code:

1. [Android app to record sound in real time and identify frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982623/android-app-to-record-sound-in-real-time-and-identify-frequency)
2. [android getting sound frequencies real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341229/android-getting-sound-frequencies-real-time)
3. http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/get-frequency-data-from-microphone-in-real-time-t16774.html

4.http://therandomlab.blogspot.co.il/2013/05/fft-audio-frequency-analysis-with.html

can anyone explain with working code - without guessing any var,
how cat i get frequency in Hz in real time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the frequency of a single sound (i.e. single guitar string, not a chord, or single voice), you can use the autocorrelation algorithm. I.e. to find shortest distance, where input signal correlates to itself.

I suggest you to read this article: https://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/high-accuracy-monophonic-pitch-estimation-using-normalized-autocorrelation/

There is C++, but it can be easily ported to Java. You can also speed up that algorithm using FFT for autocorrelation and making certain optimizations.

Comment: many thanks i already find JAVA Solution which i publish soon

Comment: @itzhar, can you post the JAVA solution please. Thanks

Comment: @itzhar did you find the solution?